# Quanteda what does the variable Types mean that is returned by summary(corpus)?

Tags: r, quanteda

I was studying the quanteda package from R and I just could not find from the documents what the variable called Types that is returned by summary(immig_corp) means.

```
require(quanteda)
require(readtext)
```

Now I create the corpus:

```
immig_corp <- corpus(data_char_ukimmig2010, 
                 docvars = data.frame(party = names(data_char_ukimmig2010)))
```

Now I would like to display some information about the corpus I have just created. Types is one of the generic attributes always given by the summary(corpus).

```
summary(immig_corp)
```

This bit returns me the following:

```
Corpus consisting of 9 documents:

         Text Types Tokens Sentences        party
         BNP  1125   3280        88          BNP
   Coalition   142    260         4    Coalition
Conservative   251    499        15 Conservative
      Greens   322    679        21       Greens
      Labour   298    683        29       Labour
      LibDem   251    483        14       LibDem
          PC    77    114         5           PC
         SNP    88    134         4          SNP
        UKIP   346    723        27         UKIP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's just concentrate on `immig_corp <- corpus(data_char_ukimmig2010)`. This returns the following:

```
Corpus consisting of 9 documents:

         Text Types Tokens Sentences
          BNP  1125   3280        88
    Coalition   142    260         4
 Conservative   251    499        15
       Greens   322    679        21
       Labour   298    683        29
       LibDem   251    483        14
           PC    77    114         5
          SNP    88    134         4
         UKIP   346    723        27
```

Now `Text` is the document name. `Sentences` is the number of sentences in the document. `Tokens` is the number of tokens in the text and `Types` is the number of unique tokens in the text. So for BNP there are 1125 unique tokens, 3280 tokens and 88 sentences.

You can recreate the counts as follows:

```
# Sentences
nsentence(immig_corp)
         BNP    Coalition Conservative       Greens       Labour       LibDem           PC          SNP         UKIP 
          88            4           15           21           29           14            5            4           27 

# Tokens
ntoken(immig_corp)
         BNP    Coalition Conservative       Greens       Labour       LibDem           PC          SNP         UKIP 
        3280          260          499          679          683          483          114          134          723 

# Types
ntype(immig_corp)
         BNP    Coalition Conservative       Greens       Labour       LibDem           PC          SNP         UKIP 
        1125          142          251          322          298          251           77           88          346
```